# Does a sentient weapon polymorphed into a creature retain the sentience's personality/alignment?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, polymorph, alignment, intelligent-magic-items

Consider the spell [*true polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph). If you turn a creature into a creature, the new creature

> retains its alignment and personality.

If you turn an object into a creature

> The creature is friendly to you and your companions.

An object typically has neither personality nor alignment, so that isn't normally an issue.

However, a sentient weapon is an object ([per Sage Advice](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2017/02/18/does-a-sentient-magic-item-count-as-a-creature/)), and does have personality and alignment.

**If you cast *true polymorph* to turn a sentient, neutral evil greatsword into a creature, does the creature retain the sword's alignment and personality?**

Which could imply that it is not friendly.

Comment: [This commentary by Jeremy Crawford](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2017/02/18/does-a-sentient-magic-item-count-as-a-creature/) would help your question to avoid some contention about whether a sentient magic item counts as an object.

Comment: @DavidCoffron Sorry, I'm not clear on what you mean. Crawford's tweet says that a sentient magic item is an object, which is what I said.

Comment: I know. You are right, I was just saying you could add it to your question if you wanted so it's less likely someone doubts your statement that it is.

Comment: @DavidCoffron Ohhhh. Good idea!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The first sentence in the description of *true polymorph* says "Choose one creature or **nonmagical** object that you can see within range." Based on this, I don't think it's possible to cast *true polymorph* on a sentient
weapon, as all sentient weapons are magical objects (as far as I know—I couldn't find anything that actually states this outright, but [as V2Blast pointed out in a comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/129449/does-a-sentient-weapon-polymorphed-into-a-creature-retain-the-sentiences-person/129454?noredirect=1#comment321422_129454), the DMG covers item sentience in the section ["Sentient Magic Items"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/dmg/sentient-magic-items-artifacts) starting on p. 214, and it appears to use the terms "sentient magic items" and "sentient items" interchangeably).

Comment: Eeyup. I completely missed that!

Comment: You might want to cite the DMG to support the statement that sentient weapons are magical; they appear in the ["Sentient Magic Items"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/dmg/sentient-magic-items-artifacts) section starting on DMG p. 214.

Comment: @V2Blast: Thanks. I haven't found anything that actually unambiguously states "all sentient weapons are magical" or "no non-magical weapon is sentient" ("Some magic items possess sentience and personality" doesn't *logically* imply that no non-magic items possess sentience and personality), but that definitely seems to be the intended situation.

Comment: Oooh, now I want a story like that... An evil sword turned dictator! Since it's impossible with basic spells, it can become a major plot point

Answer (score 7):

## RAW: No.

True Polymorph states:

> If you turn a creature into another kind of creature, [...] It retains its alignment and personality.

A sentient weapon **is not a creature**, as stated in your own question and Crawford's tweet. So, the "if" in this statement is false, thus it simply doesn't apply.

What you are doing is turning an Object into Creature. The fact that it is sentient does not change that it is an object, and thus does not change which section of the spell applies.

## Rules as DM wants

But this is a quite edgy case, and a DM might rule otherwise. If you are the DM, you are free to change this interpretation as you want and make the new creature retain the personality from before. If you are a player, ask your DM before casting the spell to check what is his ruling on this.

---

As pointed out by [sumelic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/129454/43856), you can't even cast *true polymorph* on a sentient weapon, since TP states

> Choose one creature or ***nonmagical* object** that you can see within range.

And I don't think there is a nonmagical sentient object.

Comment: It might be worth updating to address what @sumelic's answer points out: sentient weapons are magical.

Comment: One other thing, I've seen Jeremy Crawford comment that it is best to treat a sentient weapon as a construct in some circumstances, rather than an object -- but V2Blast is right in pointing out @sumelic's answer is the correct one.

Comment: @J.A.Streich I'm not sure the context you read it. I've never seen anything similar to that, and his official answer can be found here: https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/820091935868133376. A construct is a creature type. Sentient magic items do **not** have that type on them. Actually, they have none, thus "A sentient magic item has none of those types. It's an object. "

Comment: @J.A.Streich Also, if you treat the weapon as a construct, thus as a creature, sumelic's answer becomes wrong as well, since you would be targetting a creature (which can be as magical as you want).

Comment: The issue is Jeremy Crawford didn't give it as an official rules answer, he said something along the lines of "sometimes it is useful to treat sentient weapons as constructs".  My comment was written in haste, and rereading it seems to over state what was said.  I'll look to see if I can find the tweet I'm recalling.